# installing compiled rpm but ownership fails

Tags: rpm, opscenter

I have downloaded an opscenter rpm and extracted it and compiled it back to rpm with my own modifications because of there are files that I dont need. My rpm is just simply placing the files and folders of opscenter to /opt/pogi/packages directory which is owned by pogi user and group. I found wierd on during the rpm installation it looks for the opscenter user and group which should be not. please see the message during the rpm installation

```
warning: group opscenter does not exist - using root
warning: user opscenter does not exist - using root
warning: group opscenter does not exist - using root
warning: user opscenter does not exist - using root
```

please let me know if there are any steps to fix the rpm installation

Comment: Does your specfile reference that user anywhere? (In the `%files` section perhaps?) Does the rpm run scripts in `%post` that might reference it?

Comment: Hi Etan, I did not use a spec file while building, my pre/post install scripts are just a plain bash echoing "started installation" and "completed installation"

Comment: How did you "compiled it back to rpm" without using a spec file? What did you do exactly?

Comment: apache ant reads my build.xml and builds it to rpm via perl

Comment: Unless it is manually constructing the rpm by hand it is using a spec file somewhere. In any case the problem is that your package is trying to set ownership of a file to `opscenter` but no such user exists. So you need to find out where in the packaging of your rpm this is being set. (It is almost certainly in the `%files` section of the generated spec file.)

Comment: Thanks Etan, yup looks like it is. will do modify the spec file

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile is specifying ownership information for the files that specifies that user but that user doesn't exist on your system.

You need to find the part of the `%files` section of the spec file that does this and change that ... or create the user they expect to exist in the RPM.